# FBDialog Photo Sharing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am sharing photo usingFBDI `presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams` /`presentShareDialogWithPhotos` method in `FBDialogs`. This method shares photo successfully on my wall but always returns an error, meaning that it posts photos with an NSError.
Error is like....

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=103 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
 (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 103.)" 
UserInfo=0x16d874f0 {error_code=103, error_description=An unknown error occurred., app_id=593434950703264, error_reason=( { result = 1; } )}
```

Why this happen?

Comment: Facebook sdk v3.21.1 released. but this bug is not resolved. I am getting same error in photo sharing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this answer will get deleted like my previous one, but anywho...

The issue have been fixed!!!,
just update your Facebook app to v20,
released on December 8th.

See:
[Code=103 "The operation couldn’t be completed ..." in Share Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/611610228945531/)

note:
I want to add comment to the question but I don't have the privilege to do that,
so I add an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I came across the same issue, the strange thing was that is even after this error comes, just check your Facebook (for which you've shared a content), **and yes you'll feel awesome**, the content is already uploaded (shared) on Facebook. I'm also looking forward for this issue, in my checks this problem will only occurring if you're using this method `+ (FBAppCall *)presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams:(FBPhotoParams *)params clientState:(NSDictionary *)clientState handler:(FBDialogAppCallCompletionHandler)handler;` from `FBDialogs.h` means, using of Facebook application dialog for sharing.